# Any difference in meaning/usage between the phrases "from now on" and "as of now"?

Tags: time, future

Is there a particular difference in meaning or usage between the phrases "as of now" and "from now on"? Could it be said that the first is more formal or is there more to this?

Also, could these two be replaced with "going forward" in all contexts of use?

Comment: They are chalk and cheese apart.

Comment: Going forward would certainly be going backward.

Comment: It is like hitherto, and henceforth.